# OpenGraph show full image size in preview

Tags: html, django, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I want to show a thumbnail when sending a link. I tried it with using open graph and now it looks like that:

[image]

but I want it to look like this:

[image]

how can I change the size of the image in the preview.

This is my code right now:

```
  <meta property="og:image" content="/media/{{ image }}">
```

{{ image }} is just my templatetag for the image but that works like expected so there is no need to change something there.

If it's necessary I'm also able to change the service from opengraph to some other if changing the size is not possible there.

Comment: On what site are you wanting to show the preview? Twitter?

Comment: Not just on twitter also on Discord or WhatsApp..

Comment: Wanted to know which site you tried the above preview out so I could test it out too? If you open the page from the image you posted above (https://prnt.sc/dp5HXPiTB7Oy) and view source, you can check what tags they added. I can see they added some Twitter tags, `og`, etc.